# Include Java Class to JSP

Tags: jsp

I want to have a Java class pass a date, that a JSP is current doing:

Current code in the JSP

```
<fmt:parseDate var="testdate" value="Jul 30 14:45:58 2013" pattern="MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"/>
```

Reason being is I do not want this date to be available in the JSP source code and to be hidden away. Additionally, I want to be able to add other variables hidden in the Java code. This is for a commercial application and it needs certain information hidden from anyone trying to install the application browsing code. Probably not the best solution, but allows me to script a new date and compile it automatically.

How would I do this via Java, compile it and have the JSP file pick this as a variable in the JSP?

Comment: You can pass the required from one java class where you can do all formatting stuff and access on JSP.

Comment: So I import the Java class and can use the variables within?

Comment: No, don't import class , just set date and other variable in request,or session and access on JSP. Use EL syntax.